# Ember component - TypeError: store is undefined

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I am using ember 2.3. When I tried to access store inside a component, I am getting the following error in console.

[image]

This is what I have tried in component.js

```
export default Ember.Component.extend({

actions: {
  saveEmployee : function() {
      var store = this.store;

      var newEmployee = store.createRecord("employee", {
          fname: "Manu",
          lname: "Benjamin",
          email: "manu.benjamin@gmail.com",
          department: "IT Services"
      });

      newEmployee.save().then(()=> {
          console.log("Record successfully saved!!!!");
      });

  }
}
});
```

Do I need to include anything to use store in my component?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I was trying to figure out the reason for this type error. At last I found the solution from the following blog by **Josh Farrant**.

https://blog.farrant.me/how-to-access-the-store-from-within-an-ember-component/

we need to inject the store service in component.

```
store: Ember.inject.service(),
```

we can use the store injected in actions using the get function,

```
let store = this.get('store');
```

I modified my code using the above solution and it worked for me.

```
export default Ember.Component.extend({

store: Ember.inject.service(),

actions: {

  saveEmployee : function() {
      var store = this.get('store');

      var newEmployee = store.createRecord("employee", {
          fname: "Manu",
          lname: "Benjamin",
          email: "manu.benjamin@gmail.com",
          department: "IT Services"
      });

      newEmployee.save().then(() => {
          console.log("Record successfully saved!!!!");
      });

  }
}
});
```

Thanks **Josh Farrant** for the nice blog.

Comment: is store not now automatically injected into components, controllers and routes?

Answer (score 4):

This topic has been already discussed multiple times and I am sure you can find many posts on the issue. Let me repeat shortly what has been mentioned already: try to avoid using store directly within a component.

In case your design allows you to manipulate Ember store in an associated route or a controller (where the store is btw available by default), try to **send an action from a component** so that it bubbles to the controller and performs a **store manipulation in the controller**. May 
[EmberJS guides - how to send actions from components](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.3.0/components/handling-events/#toc_sending-actions) help you with that.

Comment: Thanks for the information Pavol. Now I am sending action from component to route/controller. But, Previously I was trying to access the store in component and found that using dependency injection we can done that.